# Unit, Integration or Feature Test?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, eloquent, naming-conventions, standards

A simple question: *How do you differentiate between a feature, unit and integration test?*

There are a lot of differing opinions, but I'm specifically trying to determine how to organise a Laravel test which touches a model's relationship. Here is an example if some PHP code which would require testing:

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prices::class);
}


public function getPriceAttribute($)
{
    return $this->prices()->first() * 2;
}
```

---

The test descriptions as I understand them (feel free to correct me):

**Unit test**

- Tests the smallest part of your code
- Does not touch the database
- Does not interact with any other part of the system

**Integration test**

- Tests part of the system working together
- e.g controllers which call helper functions which need to be tested together

**Feature test**

- Blackbox test
- e.g. Call an api end point, see that it has returned the correct JSON response

---

Here is my issue given those descriptions:

- My Laravel model test needs to test the smallest unit of code - the calculated accessor of a model, which makes it feel like a Unit test
- But, it touches the database when it loads the model's relationship
- It doesnt feel like an Integration test, because it is only touching other related models, not internal or external services
- Other property accessor tests in Laravel would fall under Unit tests when they do not touch the database or the model's relationships
- Separating these types of tests into integration tests would mean that a single model's tests against its properties are fragmented between integration and unit tests

**So, without mocking relationships between models, where would my test belong?**

Comment: A different perspective (very similar to your definitions) https://testing.googleblog.com/2010/12/test-sizes.html

Answer (score 2):

If I’m interpreting your original question correctly, I think the killer constraint here is:

**So, without mocking relationships between models, where would my test belong?**

If mocking isn't allowed and you're required to touch a DB then, by your/and google's definition, it has to belong as an integration/medium size test :)

---

The way I think of this is get price attribute functionality is separate from the DB.  Even though it's in the model the prices could come from anywhere.  Right now its a RDBMS but what if your org go really big and it split into another service? Basically, I believe, that the capability of `getPriceAttributes` is distinct from the storage of attributes:

```
public function getPriceAttribute($)
{
    return $this->prices()->first() * 2;
}
```

If you buy into this reasoning, it creates a logical separation that supports unit tests.  `prices()` can be mocked to returns a collection of 0, 1 & many (2) results.  This test can be executed as a unit tests (for orders of magnitude faster test execution (ie on the order of 1ms vs *potentially* 10s or 100s of ms talking to a local DB)

---

I am not familiar with php test ecosystem but one way to do this could be with a [test specific subclass](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html) (not sure if the following is valid PHP :p ):

```
class PricedModel extends YourModel {
   function __construct($stub_prices_supporting_first) {
     $this->stub_prices = $stub_prices_supporting_first;
   }

   public function prices() {
     return $this->stub_prices;
   }

}
```

*tests*

```
function test_priced_model_0_prices() {
   p = new PricedModel(new Prices(array()));
   assert.equal(null, p.getPriceAttribute());
}

function test_priced_model_1_price() {
   p = new PricedModel(new Prices(array(1)));
   assert.equal(2, p.getPriceAttribute());
}

function test_priced_model_2_prices() {
   p = new PricedModel(new Prices(array(5, 1)));
   assert.equal(10, p.getPriceAttribute());
}
```

The above should hopeuflly allow you to fully control input into the `getPriceAttribute` method to support direct IO-free unit testing.

——
Also all the unit tests above can tell you is that you’re able to process prices correctly , it doesn’t price any feedback on if you’re able to query prices !

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm not sure I can translate the second part of your answer into something workable with PHP, but I guess youre talking about mocks and stubs. I've used those elsewhere, but there always seems to be the type of in-between test (like the one in my question). Mocking it would be very difficult, as Laravel is using the method as a magic accessor.

I think youre right about it being an integration test though.

Comment: What about moving ‘getPriceAttribute’ to its own standalone function which accepts the prices return value? This way it should be easy to call it directly

Answer (score 1):

What distinguishes the tests is their respective goal:

- Unit-testing aims at findings those bugs that can be found in isolated small parts of the software.  (Note that this does not say you *must* isolate - it only means your focus is on the isolated code.  Isolation and mocking often enough are not needed to reach this goal: Think of a call to a `sin` function - you almost never need to mock this, you let your system under test just call the original one.)
- Integration testing aims at findings bugs in the interaction of two or more components, for example mutual misconceptions about an interface.  These bugs can not be found in the isolated software: If you test code in isolation, you also write your tests on your (possibly wrong) understanding of the other components.
- Feature tests as you describe them will then have the goal to find further bugs, which the other tests so far could not detect.  One example for such a bug could be, that an old version of the feature was integrated (which was correct at that time, but lacked some functionality).

The conclusion, although it may be surprising, is, that it is not in the stricter sense *forbidden* to make data base accesses in unit-testing.  Consider the following scenario:  You start writing unit-tests and mock the data base accesses.  Later, you realize you can be more lazy and just use the data base without mocking - but otherwise leave all the tests as they are.  Your tests have not changed, and they will continue finding the bugs in the isolated code as before.  They may run a bit slower now, and the setup may be more complex than with the mocked data base.  However, the goal of the test suite was the same - with and without mocking the data base.

This scenario simplifies things a bit, because there may be test cases that can only be done with a mock: For example, testing the case that the data base gets corrupted in a specific way and your code handles this properly.  With the real data base such test cases may be practically impossible to set up.